# WSO2 identity server user customization

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We are currently looking to use the WSO2 identity server for SSO via SAML2. Everything is working fine but we need to add custom attributes to the user profile and i don't find any documentation about it. We plan to use a JDBC store (mysql). From what, I have found on the web, it seems to be possible but I have not found any documentation on how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using JDBC user store manager, It is easy to add custom attributes.  You can use claim management configuration UI in the management console. Under the wso2 claim dialect, you need to add a new claim mapping.  In claim mapping,  you can provide any mapped attribute for JDBC user store. But, if you are using LDAP or AD or any custom user store,  you need to provide a proper mapping between user store attribute and the claim.  You can find more details from [here](http://soasecurity.org/2012/05/02/claim-management-with-wso2-identity-server/).

Then you need to select newly added claim uri in the SAML2 SSO configuration page.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I was able to successfully to add a custom claim to the profile. However, If I don't use the http://wso2.org/claims schema to add the claim, it does not appears in the user profile. I tried to create my own schema and claims and it was not added to the profile. Have you any idea why?

Comment: As i think, Claim dialects are the set of claims that are specific to protocol. You can see there are openId, SCIM and wso2 claim dialect. So openid ask the user attribute using openid claim dialect. Like that, WSO2 Identity server APIs (UI) ask claims the user attribute using wso2 claim dialect which is  wos2.org/claim. Therefore if you are using claim within WSO2 related APIs, you need to use wso2 dialect.

Comment: I successfully added a claim to the wso2.org/claims schema. Now i want to add this claim to user profile via SCIM rest endpoints.Do u have any idea ?

Comment: i guess. i provided answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729142/add-create-custom-user-profile-details-to-wso2-is

Comment: How to change "Default dialect for WSO2 Carbon" (Claim set of this dialect is used for default user profile), I would like to add EmployeeID there. How can I do that? Please guide....Thanks, Neha

Answer (score 2):

To change the fields in the User Profile:

Through trial-and-error I found that these fields are determined by the settings of the individual claims fields in the Claim Management / wso2.org/claims list.  If you first note the order of the fields in the User Profile, they correspond to the order of how the individual claims are set in the claims list (in this case wso2.org/claims). But you can only going into the detail of each individual claim.

Click Configure tab -- Claims Management -- wso2.org/claims and you will see this list of all claims for wso2.org.  Pull the drop down for each claim that is in the User Profile and you will see that the claim's "Display Order" corresponds to the order of the field in the User Profile.

To change the order, click Edit for that claim and either change the Display Order field to another number, or change it to zero to take it off the User Profile (also uncheck "Supported By Default" and uncheck "Required").

To add a field to the User Profile, click the drop down for the claim you wish to add, Edit it, change its Display Order from zero to a number of your own choosing, check "Supported By Default, and check "Required" if needed.

Repeat for each field you need to remove or add.  Your User Profile will now have the fields you want.

Comment: I forgot to add that I assume the above basic procedure will work for any other set of claims.

Comment: Thanks, but to add custom claim there (Available Claims for http://wso2.org/claims) in order to make available in UserProfile ? Please help...Thanks, Neha

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thanks ! Still up-to-date in 2019 with WSO2IS 5.7.0