# Add/create custom user profile details to wso2 IS

Tags: wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

I have added a new custom attribute named policyid in claim management(as per the [post](http://soasecurity.org/2012/05/02/claim-management-with-wso2-identity-server/) ), Now i want to add the profile details via SCIM endpoint.I tried with the following curl command..

> curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data
>   "{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"gunasinghe","givenName":"hasinitg"},"userName":'jouhar',"password":"password","**policyid":"123"**,"emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"hasini_home.com","type":"home"},{"value":"hasini_work.com","type":"work"}]}" --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://example.com:9443/wso2/scim/Users

But its not working...pls help..

**My primary storage changed to JDBC User store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the SCIM specification, there are fixed set of default attributes for the user object. This set is defined to ensure the interoperability. Most of time, it can cater to most of the industry's identity management requirements. But according the spec,  you can even add custom attributes. It is supported by WSO2IS.  But you may need to do some more work. Please refer WSOIS docs for more details from [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS460/Extensible+SCIM+User+Schemas+With+WSO2+Identity+Server)

Comment: the link is not responding. Please assist